# Neo4j driver instantiation fails with ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:11002

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j gives me this error:

```
+ Error: Neo4j driver instantiation failed !
 Neo4jError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:11002
```

I am getting this error while running my code. I have installed all necessary dependencies.

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow, This question does not provide enough information always try to provide some information related to what you tried so far with some of your code. Help people to help you.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: This is a network error, so we will need to know how you are running it, and what you are running it on. Without any further information, the best we can offer is disable your firewall temporarily to see if it is blocking traffic to port 11002. If that fixes it, you will need to open port 11002 on your firewall.